# Build <select> from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to build select tag from database but when I return the string I got NULL.
Please Help:

**PHP Code**

```
<?php       
function getDropDown($table,$value,$display){

    $dbConx = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "fw_request");

    if ($dbConx->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    /* Select queries return a resultset */

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";

    $result = $dbConx->query($sql);

    $a="<select name='streams'>";   
    $a="<option value=\"0\">Choose Stream</option>";


    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $a="<option value=\"1\" selected>1</option>";   
        $a='<br>';  
    }
    $a="</select>"; 
    return $a;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
Sterams:<?php echo getDropDown('streams','Streams_ID','Streams_ShortName');
```

The Query is OK.

Thanks,
Cfir.

Comment: You keep overwriting the value of $a rather than adding to it.

Comment: Also, you keep adding `<br>` tags inside the select which is invalid markup.

Comment: You don't need break tags in a select list @ClémentMalet

Comment: Your code is good for a SQL injection - where is it hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overwriting $a, what you need to do is add to $a by concatenating -

```
$a = "<select name='streams'>";   
$a .= "<option value=\"0\">Choose Stream</option>";
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   $a .= "<option value=\"1\" selected>1</option>";   
}
$a .= "</select>"; 
return $a;
```

Comment: selected> with each option will repeat

Comment: That is true @RamSharma, but the OP did not post what the results of the table would be.

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the value of $a.

Do like this

```
function getDropDown($table, $value, $display) {

    $dbConx = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "fw_request");

    if ($dbConx->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $dbConx->connect_errno . ") " . $dbConx->connect_error;
    }

    /* Select queries return a resultset */

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";

    $result = $dbConx->query($sql);

    $a = "<select name='streams'>";
    $a .= "<option value=\"0\">Choose Stream</option>";


    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {


        $a .= "<option value=\"1\" selected>1</option>";


    }
    $a .= "</select>";
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: `<br>` tags have no business inside a `<select>`, though... just leave that out